# How to list an image sequence in an efficient way? Numercial sequence comparison in Python

Tags: python, regex, glob

I have a directory of 9 images:

```
image_0001, image_0002, image_0003
image_0010, image_0011
image_0011-1, image_0011-2, image_0011-3
image_9999
```

I would like to be able to list them in an efficient way, like this (4 entries for 9 images):

```
(image_000[1-3], image_00[10-11], image_0011-[1-3], image_9999)
```

Is there a way in python, to return a directory of images, in a short/clear way (without listing every file)?

So, possibly something like this:

list all images, sort numerically, create a list (counting each image in sequence from start).
When an image is missing (create a new list), continue until original file list is finished.
Now I should just have some lists that contain non broken sequences.

I'm trying to make it easy to read/describe a list of numbers.  If I had a sequence of 1000 consecutive files It could be clearly listed as file[0001-1000] rather than file['0001','0002','0003' etc...]

**Edit1**(based on suggestion): Given a flattened list, how would you derive the glob patterns?

**Edit2**  I'm trying to break the problem down into smaller pieces.  Here is an example of part of the solution:
data1 works, data2 returns 0010 as 64, data3 (the realworld data) doesn't work:

```
# Find runs of consecutive numbers using groupby.  The key to the solution
# is differencing with a range so that consecutive numbers all appear in
# same group.
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import *

data1=[01,02,03,10,11,100,9999]
data2=[0001,0002,0003,0010,0011,0100,9999]
data3=['image_0001','image_0002','image_0003','image_0010','image_0011','image_0011-2','image_0011-3','image_0100','image_9999']

list1 = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data1), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    list1.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))
print 'data1'
print list1

list2 = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data2), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    list2.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))
print '\ndata2'
print list2
```

returns:

```
data1
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 11], [100], [9999]]

data2
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 9], [64], [9999]]
```

Comment: Why `image_00[10-11]` and not `image_001[0-1]`?

Comment: image_00[10-11] or image_001[0-1], yes i guess that is one less character

Comment: Cynically: yes, there is a way.  I doubt (but could be wrong) that there is some library function to do this.  Write some code, ask something more specific (e.g. how can I compare strings for similarity) after you already did `os.listdir(path)`, etc.

Comment: It would be great if there was a library to do this. I guess that video editing & compositing software use image sequences as single source filein, so this problem has been solved before.

Comment: @Nick T, I've updated my question above, trying to break the problem into more detail. thanks

Comment: I'd agree that there probably isn't a library to do this.  Also another point to consider is what you mean by efficient.  Do you want to absolutely minimize the number of entries required to describe the directory, or just reduce it by a certain factor?  Is human-readability of the resulting listing a priority?

Comment: @waffle paradox @martineau - well 'reduce by a certain factor' and make it human readable would be an acceptable goal

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by "efficient way"?

Comment: Is this efficent? `image_['0001', '0002', '0003', '0010', '0011', '0011-1', '0011-2', '0011-3', '9999']`

Comment: @martineau listing each file like image_['0001', '0002', '0003'] is what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm trying to make it easy to read consecutive sequences in short form.

Comment: Actually that was one entry for all nine files. OK, then is `'0011'` in the sequence `['0010','0011']` or `['0011', '0011-1', '0011-2', '0011-3']`?

Comment: Also if dash '-' characters are in file names, won't that conflict with using them to specify ranges?

Comment: I don't think Python even has a way to increment a name like that, i.e. going from 'image_0001' to 'image_0002'. So I doubt there's a built-in solution to the problem.

Comment: The leading zeros on the data2 constants are turning them into octal - 0100 is 64 in base 10. And I don't see any way to extend your `groupby` solution to strings.

Comment: Obviously Frédéric Hamidi has better vision than I do. Check his updated answer.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - Thanks for all your help. Your suggestion to 'test each element to see if it is equal to the previous element+1' has helped me to look at problems differently, and break them down into smaller chunks.  I've really learnt a lot from you guys. Thanks again to everyone for all your assistance (this was a very interesting problem for me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working implementation of what you want to achieve, using the code you added as a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools
import re

# This algorithm only works if DATA is sorted.
DATA = ["image_0001", "image_0002", "image_0003",
        "image_0010", "image_0011",
        "image_0011-1", "image_0011-2", "image_0011-3",
        "image_0100", "image_9999"]

def extract_number(name):
    # Match the last number in the name and return it as a string,
    # including leading zeroes (that's important for formatting below).
    return re.findall(r"\d+$", name)[0]

def collapse_group(group):
    if len(group) == 1:
        return group[0][1]  # Unique names collapse to themselves.
    first = extract_number(group[0][1])  # Fetch range
    last = extract_number(group[-1][1])  # of this group.
    # Cheap way to compute the string length of the upper bound,
    # discarding leading zeroes.
    length = len(str(int(last)))
    # Now we have the length of the variable part of the names,
    # the rest is only formatting.
    return "%s[%s-%s]" % (group[0][1][:-length],
        first[-length:], last[-length:])

groups = [collapse_group(tuple(group)) \
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(DATA),
        lambda(index, name): index - int(extract_number(name)))]

print groups
```

This prints `['image_000[1-3]', 'image_00[10-11]', 'image_0011-[1-3]', 'image_0100', 'image_9999']`, which is what you want.

**HISTORY:** I initially answered the question backwards, as @Mark Ransom pointed out below. For the sake of history, my original answer was:

You're looking for [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html). Try:

```
import glob
images = glob.glob("image_[0-9]*")
```

Or, using your example:

```
images = [glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in ("image_000[1-3]*",
    "image_00[10-11]*", "image_0011-[1-3]*", "image_9999*")]
images = [image for seq in images for image in seq]  # flatten the list
```

Comment: I think this solution is backwards from what the question is asking. Given a flattened list, how would you derive the glob patterns?

Comment: @Mark, you're right, I misunderstood the question (and its title really should be "Given a flattened list, how would you derive the glob patterns?"). I think I'll get some sleep before giving it another try :]

Comment: @Frédéric @Mark. Thankyou both for your assistance.  I'm really enjoying this problem.  I'm learning as I go.

Comment: @Frédéric, based on the number of upvotes you've gotten I'd say you're not the only one who misunderstood.

Comment: @Frédéric - THANKYOU - thats is exactly what i wanted to achieve.  This is a really clear and readable result.  I'll experiment with it and get back in touch. :o) Perfect

Comment: You're welcome, your question was quite an interesting challenge to solve :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the list Comprehension is not readable, can you break it up so it is readable.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I found your question to be a fascinating puzzle.  I've left how to
"compress" the numeric ranges up to you (marked as a TODO), as there are
different ways to accomplish that depending on how you like it formatted and if
you want the minimum number of elements or the minimum string description
length.

This solution uses a simple regular expression (digit strings) to classify each string into two groups: static and variable.  After the data is classified, I use groupby to collect the 
static data into longest matching groups to achieve the summary effect.  I mix integer index sentinals into the result (in matchGrouper) so I can re-select the varying parts from all elements (in unpack).

```
import re
import glob
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def classifyGroups(iterable, reObj=re.compile('\d+')):
    """Yields successive match lists, where each item in the list is either
    static text content, or a list of matching values.

     * `iterable` is a list of strings, such as glob('images/*')
     * `reObj` is a compiled regular expression that describes the
            variable section of the iterable you want to match and classify
    """
    def classify(text, pos=0):
        """Use a regular expression object to split the text into match and non-match sections"""
        r = []
        for m in reObj.finditer(text, pos):
            m0 = m.start()
            r.append((False, text[pos:m0]))
            pos = m.end()
            r.append((True, text[m0:pos]))
        r.append((False, text[pos:]))
        return r

    def matchGrouper(each):
        """Returns index of matches or origional text for non-matches"""
        return [(i if t else v) for i,(t,v) in enumerate(each)]

    def unpack(k,matches):
        """If the key is an integer, unpack the value array from matches"""
        if isinstance(k, int):
            k = [m[k][1] for m in matches]
        return k

    # classify each item into matches
    matchLists = (classify(t) for t in iterable)

    # group the matches by their static content
    for key, matches in groupby(matchLists, matchGrouper):
        matches = list(matches)
        # Yield a list of content matches.  Each entry is either text
        # from static content, or a list of matches
        yield [unpack(k, matches) for k in key]
```

Finally, we add enough logic to perform pretty printing of the output, and run an example.

```
def makeResultPretty(res):
    """Formats data somewhat like the question"""
    r = []
    for e in res:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            # TODO: collapse and simplify ranges as desired here
            if len(set(e))<=1:
                # it's a list of the same element
                e = e[0]
            else: 
                # prettify the list
                e = '['+' '.join(e)+']'
        r.append(e)
    return ''.join(r)

fnList = sorted(glob.glob('images/*'))
re_digits = re.compile(r'\d+')
for res in classifyGroups(fnList, re_digits):
    print makeResultPretty(res)
```

My directory of images was created from your example.  You can replace fnList with the following list for testing:

```
fnList = [
 'images/image_0001.jpg',
 'images/image_0002.jpg',
 'images/image_0003.jpg',
 'images/image_0010.jpg',
 'images/image_0011-1.jpg',
 'images/image_0011-2.jpg',
 'images/image_0011-3.jpg',
 'images/image_0011.jpg',
 'images/image_9999.jpg']
```

And when I run against this directory, my output looks like:

```
StackOverflow/3926936% python classify.py
images/image_[0001 0002 0003 0010].jpg
images/image_0011-[1 2 3].jpg
images/image_[0011 9999].jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I am very unsure of what you are doing. Could you add some comments that help me relate to the example image_0002, image_0003 etc...  If you could add a test list, I might be able to step through and run your solution bit by bit.

Comment: THANKYOU for your time Shane.  I'll continue looking at your itertools solution; I think I can learn a lot from it.  The Edit2 in the original post, was a result of googling/studying your well commented solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
def ranges(sorted_list):
    first = None
    for x in sorted_list:
        if first is None:
            first = last = x
        elif x == increment(last):
            last = x
        else:
            yield first, last
            first = last = x
    if first is not None:
        yield first, last
```

The `increment` function is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit:** here's an example of how it would be used with integers instead of strings as input.

```
def increment(x): return x+1

list(ranges([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10]))
[(1, 4), (6, 8), (10, 10)]
```

For each contiguous range in the input you get a pair indicating the start and end of the range. If an element isn't part of a range, the start and end values are identical.

Comment: thanks I don't really understand. So, assume I've sorted the files into a list:  sorted_list = ['image_0001','image_0002','image_0003','image_0010', 'image_0011'] ... can you explain what you have shown me.  For each item in the sorted_list (if you increment it, check to see if it exists in the rest of the list)???

Comment: @user, this algorithm tests each element to see if it should be included in the current sequence by testing to see if it's equal to last+1. If it is, then the current sequence is extended; otherwise the sequence is yielded as a tuple and the current sequence is reset to the new element. If we can assure that the input is not empty, this could even be simplified.

Comment: Thankyou. Ok, so I understand that it tests each element to see if it is equal to the previous element+1.  I don't understand "otherwise the sequence is yielded as a tuple"...