# Regarding comparison of 2 image sequences in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, image, comparison, sequence

I have images in 2 different folders, 100 images in each of the 2 folders.The images belong to photographs taken from 2 different simulations.The 100 images are the 100 time steps of the 2 simulations.I wish to compare the images frame by frame. Can they be displayed on the screen with some software,such that I just need to press the arrow keys(up/down) and the images from the 2 sequences will BOTH move forward/backward by one step, so that I can compare the 2 images frame by frame simultaneously. I do not wish to mathematically subtract images, just compare them visually with the eyes.

Windows, I came to know has avisynth and pdplayer for the above. avxsynth is the Linux version of avisynth,but it is unstable in my computer.

This is the only question I found,before posting this and it is off-topic
[How to list an image sequence in an efficient way? Numercial sequence comparison in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926936/how-to-list-an-image-sequence-in-an-efficient-way-numercial-sequence-comparison)

Can anyone please suggest any other option ?

Comment: you want to ask about this on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php), specifically [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php), and a simple shell script to create a new set of images?  (Where each new image consists of your two previous images glued (montaged) together side by side.)

ImageMagick will also support subtraction of images, which can be montaged into the new set too, should you change your mind about that.

Or the creation of animations where the images oscillate between your two runs so you can compare them more easily.  (i.e. create a 3rd folder with 100 new images each of which is an animation alternating between the two runs.)

You may want to consider generating a little html with a shell-script, and putting each image or set of images into its own webpage along with forward and backward buttons.  It's pretty trivial, and gives you a nice little web-browser slideshow.  You can pick up the necessary HTML in a couple of minutes.  You wouldn't need much more than the A HREF and IMG tags.  Webbrowsers support local file:// URLs.  (Again, a 3rd directory with 100 html files linking to images in the first 2 directories.)

Or you could generate one big webpage with all the images in it, and just scroll up and down...

---

---

> > > > I am new to shell scripting, can you please give me a shell script. I could not find out how to write the shell script. I could make use of montage. Suppose the 2 directories are dir1 and dir2, and each of them has five files file_001,file_002,file_003,file_004,file_005 can you please post the shell script ??

Sure.  I happen to like TCSH (or CSH) for this, just for the **:t** option...

Note:  montage output filename needs an extension to tell montage what the output graphics filetype is...  (e.g. .jpeg or .gif or whatever...)

```
% mkdir dir3
% ls -a *

dir1:
./        ../       file_001  file_002  file_003  file_004  file_005

dir2:
./        ../       file_001  file_002  file_003  file_004  file_005

dir3:
./  ../

% foreach VAR ( dir1/file* )
    montage -background #000000 -geometry +4+4 $VAR dir2/$VAR:t dir3/out_$VAR:t.jpeg

  end

% ls d*
dir1:
./        ../       file_001  file_002  file_003  file_004  file_005

dir2:
./        ../       file_001  file_002  file_003  file_004  file_005

dir3:
./                 out_file_001.jpeg  out_file_003.jpeg  out_file_005.jpeg
../                out_file_002.jpeg  out_file_004.jpeg
```

Nothing to it...   For HTML you could just echo text into a file...

```
% set Q = '"'
% mkdir dirfoo
% foreach VAR ( dir1/file* )
     echo "<html><head></head><body><img src=${Q}../$VAR${Q}></img></body></html>" >> dirfoo/$VAR:t.html

  end
```

That sort of thing...

Perhaps:

```
% foreach VAR ( dir1/file* )
     echo "<html><head></head><body><table><tr><td><img src=${Q}../$VAR${Q}></img></td><td><img src=${Q}../dir2/$VAR:t${Q}></img></td></tr></table></body></html>" >> dirfoo/$VAR:t.html

  end
```

Comment: Regarding this,
Have you considered using ImageMagick, specifically montage, and a simple shell script to create a new set of images? (Where each new image consists of your two previous images glued (montaged) together side by side.)

I am new to shell scripting, can you please give me a shell script. I could not find out how to write the shell script.
I could make use of montage.

Suppose the 2 directories are dir1 and dir2,
and each of them has five files file_001,file_002,file_003,file_004,file_005

can you please post the shell script ??